# Enviar dados para um controller via jquery sem retorno

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Estou trabalhando num projeto em Laravel. Em determinada parte eu preciso enviar dados para um controller via jquery e a partir dos dados obtidos no controller, redirecionar para outra view. Como posso fazer isso? Eu costumo usar Ajax, mas com ele acho que não tem como.

Ajax que tentei :

```
         $.ajax({
                url: "{{ URL::route('checkout.concluir') }}",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  forma_pagamento : forma_pagamento,
                  endereco_id : endereco_id,
                  frete : frete
                },
                cache: false,
                processData:true,
                success: function(data)
                {   
                  window.location.href = "{{ URL::route('checkout.concluir',  data ) }}";
                }
            });

         });
```

Retorno do controller:

```
return View::make('frontend.checkout.concluido', $this->data);
```

Comment: Ola, ja tentou dar console.log("{{ URL::route('checkout.concluir',  data ) }}"); para verificar se o caminho esta correto? Acho que o que e window.location.assign("{{ URL::route('checkout.concluir',  data ) }}")

Comment: Uma dica: Não é melhor usar um atributo `data` do jQuery ou  uma tag meta para fazer isso? `<meta name="laravel_route" content="{{ app('url')->route('minha.rota') }}">`